# Specify jndi.properties location outside built JAR

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jndi

I'm using Intellij.

I have a jndi.properties file (used for connecting to a Wildfly instance).

By default, Maven includes this file inside the JAR , after build. This is not good, as the jndi.properties contains the URL and credentials to the Wildfly instance and in production these will be different.

I managed to exclude the jndi.properties file by placing it in a separate folder (called config), and then in Intellij -> Module Settings -> Sources I marked the config folder as Resources and Excluded. This way, when I run the application inside Intellij, it works fine. But when I build the JAR, even if I place a folder called config outside the JAR, I still get an exception because no jndi.properties file is found in the classpath.

The same happens if I declare the config folder in the Dependencies tab in the Module Settings.

I also tried specifying the classpath when I run the java cmd line tool, but it seems that -cp does not work along with -jar.

I know two alternatives, but I don't really like them: have jndi.properties in JAVA_HOME/lib (not good, it will be common for all applications) or at runtime (-Djava.naming.provider.url etc, not as clear as a configuration file in my opinion).

Is there any way I could specify the jndi.properties file location at runtime?